# Keyboard & Mouse not Functioning in Startup Repair

Tags: macos, usb, boot-camp, imac

I have an iMac, and have installed Windows 7 through Boot Camp a few years ago. Recently after I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10, I didn't like it and wanted to go back to Windows 7. Windows rebooted and started the startup repair. The problem is, the keyboard and mouse are not working in startup repair, so I am stuck. I googled and learnt USB 3.0 ports on start up repair do not work, but my iMac only has 3.0 ports and nothing else. How am I going to fix this situation?

Comment: What year/model iMac do you have?

Comment: iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2013)
2,9 GHz Intel Core i5
8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 1024 MB

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Boot into Windows > Install Drivers Below > Try Startup Again

Check out the USB host drivers and update them if you can.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/21129/USB-3-0-Driver-Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver-for-Intel-7-Series-C216-Chipset-Family?product=65855